# Unit Test Problem

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image]My Test class not covering all the code in this class plz help me to resolve this

Here it is my Class

```
public class emailCon1 {

    public map<string,string> m{set;get;}
    public list<contact> con{set;get;}

    public emailCon1()
    {
    m=new map<string,string>();
    con=[select lastname,email from contact];

         for(contact c:con)
         {
             m.put(c.email,c.lastname);
         }
    }
}
```

It is my Test Class

```
@isTest
public class emailCon1_Tc
{

    static testMethod void testMthd()
    {
        map<string,string> m=new  map<string,string>();
            contact c=new contact();
         emailCon1 ec1=new emailCon1();
          c.lastname='YYY';
         c.email='XXX@gmail.com';
        m.put(c.email,c.lastname);
    }
}
```

Comment: what lines are not covered? How much much percent is covered? I little more information would make things easy for us.

Comment: Yes,definitely 85% covered,with in for loop code not covered not only this code many times i faced same thing with for loop.any help appreciable..

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting full test coverage is because you are not inserting the `Contact` record, so the code would not of been iterating over the `for loop` in your code.

This code should give you full test coverage:

```
@isTest
public class emailCon1_Tc
{
    static testMethod void testMthd() {
        String email = 'XXX@gmail.com';
        String lastName = 'YYY';
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = lastName, Email = email);
        insert c;
        emailCon1_Tc ec = new emailCon1_Tc();

        System.assertEquals(1, ec.con.size());
        System.assertEquals(c.Id, ec.con[0].Id);

        System.assertEquals(lastName, ec.m.get(email));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi BarCotter,Still its have problem its unable to cover for loop code.

Comment: If the code I posted runs and all the asserts pass then the `for loop` is definitely being executed. It could be the UI that displays the code coverage that is wrong. I know that UI has been buggy in the past.

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer for my Question just 'seeAllData' made me to cover 100% code coverage thanks every one for helping me to resolve issue.

> Here i covered NumberOfCons Trigger and emailCon1,emailCon classes

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)

public class emailCon_Tc

{

  static testMethod void testMthd()

    {
        contact c=new contact();
        map<string,string> m=new  map<string,string>();
        set<string> e=new set<string>();        
        set<string> n=new set<string>();
         emailCon1 ec1=new emailCon1();
         emailCon ec=new emailCon();  
         c.lastname='YYY';
         c.email='XXX@gmail.com';
         insert c;

         c.lastname='YYYY';
         update c;
         delete c;
    }
}
```

Comment: SeeAllData=true is not best practice and should only be used for special cases such as needing an sObject that can't be created via a testmethod such as ContentWorkspaces or DatedConversionRate - otherwise, testemthods should always create their own testdata